# How to query how many gmail accounts are logged in?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

For a webExtension I'm trying to check the gmail inboxes by sending a xmlhttprequest to:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/feed/atom
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/feed/atom
```

... and so on for each account. I want to do this for all currently logged in accounts, but I dont know how to find out that number.

Of course, there is a dumb way, in that I just keep incrementing the u/#/ until I loop back to /u/0/, and do a check there.

But that is slow, since I'd then have to wait for the async to return, hopfully there will be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about gmail specifically, but you could use [browser.cookies.getAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) to read all the user cookies for "mail.google.com" (or accounts.google.com or similar).

This assumes you know the name of the cookie(s) you are looking for, so that you can infer on how many accounts the user is logged in.

Also, make sure to add the `cookies` permission to your manifest.json

```
browser.cookies.getAll({ domain: 'mail.google.com' })
  .then(cookies => {
    // do something with the cookies
  });
```

If instead you can assume that each gmail inbox is open in some tab, then you could just query all the current tabs:

```
browser.tabs.query({ url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/*" })
  .then(tabs => {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      // do an XHR request to tab.url or just extract the inbox ID for later use
    });
  })
```